# Github, tried to push files more than 100mb, made other changes to files less than 100mb, removed the large files but still cannot push, its stuck

Tags: github

Had a project to master and added some files larger than 100 MB into the folder. I tried to push the repo but could not. Then I removed the files but at the same time made a lot of changes to other files which are less than 100MB. Tried to push again but the same error even though the large-size files are removed from the repository. I am trying to push the repo no as it is but GitHub looks like is stuck and won't let me do it as it usually works. Any help on how to push the current project in the repo as it is right now?

Comment: once a file has been committed, it can't be removed from the repo (easily) because that'll change the history. It'll be in the repo forever even if you delete it in a newer commit. For large files it's recommended to use git LFS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in the Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-the-git-repository)

Comment: Had a look at them but I am not sure if those completely solve the problem, the best and easier method for right now that I am looking at is the old good method to zip the current folder and unzip it and store it in GitHub XD,

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may have to clear the large file from your commit history first. I would try using git reset --soft HEAD~1 or however many commits ago it was (you can find out by using the git log --oneline). Then I would just remove the files from the staging area using git reset .